# Dismiss ViewController which was programmatically presented in ViewController nested in NavigationController crashes, but not every time

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

When i try to dismiss a ViewController which was presented programmatically in a ViewController which is nested in a NavigationController i seem to get a

## libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

every once in a while without further information given.

My ViewController which is presented modally above the nested one:

```
class RefreshController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var main: UIView!
@IBOutlet var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    spinner.startAnimating()
    label.text = .localized("refreshing") + " ..."
    
    main.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}

public func hideRefresh(_ contr: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (() -> Swift.Void)){
    contr.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        refreshController = nil
        completion()
    })
}

class func showRefresh(_ contr: UIViewController!, completion: @escaping (() -> Swift.Void)){
    refreshController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "refreshController") as! RefreshController
    
    contr.present(refreshController, animated: true, completion: {
        completion()
    })
}
}
```

I have a global variable refreshController which defines itself as the currently presented controller when it is shown to access it at every time.

In the nested ViewController i call:

```
refreshController.hideRefresh(self, completion: {
//code goes here, after the controller dismissed
}
```

(The completion part is due to the animations, which sometimes conflicts with UIAlerts which should be presented)

Does anyone has experiences with this? Or is it just a bug in the latest iOS 10.2 (14C82) beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `dismiss` on the presenting viewController, not on the presented one:

```
public func hideRefresh(_ contr: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (() -> Swift.Void)){
    // instead of contr.presentedViewController?.dismiss...
    contr.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        refreshController = nil
        completion()
    })
}
```

Comment: I got it working, i think it was due to the order of calls